# aeson: Add a single key to toJSON result

Tags: haskell, aeson

I found the following solution for my problem on [artyom.me/aeson](https://artyom.me/aeson#extended-records). However, it looks a bit bloated for the task of adding a single key to a `toJSON` result. Shouldn't there be an easier solution?

```
instance ToJSON RussianName where
  toJSON RussianName{..} = Object $
    toObject russianName <>
    fromList ["patronymic" .= russianPatronymic]

toObject :: ToJSON a => a -> Object
toObject a = case toJSON a of
  Object o -> o
  _        -> error "toObject: value isn't an Object"
```

which at least also needs

```
import Data.Aeson
import Data.Monoid ((<>))
import GHC.Exts (fromList)
```

Comment: I think you can work something much smaller with [`aeson-lens`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-lens-0.5.0.0)...

Comment: `Data.Monoid` is a common thing to import, and `(<>)` is a common operator. The `fromList` is just a way of building the relevant hash map -- without it, the tutorial would need either to use the [`fromList` from `Data.HashMap.Lazy`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/unordered-containers-0.2.7.2/docs/Data-HashMap-Lazy.html#v:fromList) or to enable the `OverloadedLists` extension. As far as the imports go, I wouldn't say it is bloated.

Comment: To add on to @duplode's point, `(<>)` is (probably) going to be added to the Prelude in the next major version of `base` (`5.0.0`). At that point, you'll only need to turn on `OverloadedLists` and import `Data.Aeson`.

Comment: with lenses and the lens-aeson package (though it seems that would violate the spirit of the question): `toJSON russianName & _Object . at "patronymic" ?~ toJSON russianPatronymic`

Comment: I like the aeson-lens version since it seems to avoid the potential run time error and avoids adding a new function. I would accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this without extra libraries like this:

```hs
import Data.Aeson.Key qualified as Key
import Data.Aeson.KeyMap qualified as KeyMap

addFieldToJSON :: Text -> Value -> Value -> Value
addFieldToJSON field val = \case
  Object obj -> Object (KeyMap.insert (Key.fromText field) val obj)
  otherJson -> otherJson
```

Sample usage:

```hs
addFieldToJSON "newField" newValue oldJSON
```

Hope it is useful!